# What's the difference between "(ex1)|(ex2)|(ex3)" and "[(ex1)(ex2)(ex3)]"

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create some general code to ease the usage of regexes, and thinking how to implement the OR function.

The title is pretty accurate (ex1,ex2,ex3 are any regular expressions). Not considering grouping, what's the difference between:

```
"(ex1)|(ex2)|(ex3)"
```

and

```
"[(ex1)(ex2)(ex3)]"
```

These both should be an or relation between the named regexes, i just might be missing something. Any way one is more efficient than the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(ex1)|(ex2)|(ex3)
```

Here you are capturing `ex1`, `ex2` and `ex3`.

Here:

```
[(ex1)(ex2)(ex3)]
```

`(` and `)` are quoted and treated as is since they're enclosed in `[` and `]` ([character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)), it matches `(`, `)`, `e`, `x`, `1`, `2` and `3`.

Note that it's equivalent to (the order is not important):

```
[ex123)(]
```

Important notes on character sets:

The caret (^) and the hyphen (-) can be included as is. If you want to include hyphen, you should place it in the very beginning of the character class. If you want to match the caret as a part of the character set, you should not put it as the first character:

- `[^]x]` matches anything that's **not** `]` and `x` where `[]^x]` matches `]`, `^` or `x`
- `[a-z]` matches all letters from `a` to `z` where `[-az]` matches `-`, `a` and `z`

Comment: Um, i don't consider grouping yet, but don't fully understand your answer. So what are the groups in either case?

Comment: @AttilaNeparáczki: There are 3 groups in first case, and 0 group in second case.

Answer (score 5):

`(ex1)|(ex2)|(ex3)` matches `ex1` (available in group 1), `ex2` (available in group 2) or `ex3` (available in group 3)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KM0GufZ6IeOfC-Gl)

---

`[(ex1)(ex2)(ex3)]` matches `(`, `e`, `x`, `1`, `2`, `3` or `)`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/E7o09h4G_Le66OE3)

Comment: @AttilaNeparáczki No.

Comment: @AttilaNeparáczki `[]` creates a character class, literally "one of the chars between the brackets".

Comment: fancy drawings :D can you please add that [(ex1)(ex2)(ex3)] essentially equals [()ex123], and i can accept this as an answer? thats an important note imo.

Answer (score 1):

They're fundamentally different.

`(ex1)|(ex2)|(ex3)` defines a series of alternating capture groups for the literal text `ex1`, `ex2`, and `ex3`. That is, either `ex1`, if present, will be captured in the first capture group; or `ex2`, if present, will be captured in a second capture group; or `ex3`, if present, will be captured in a third group. (This would be a fairly odd expression, a more likely one would be `(ex1|ex2|ex3)`, which matches and captures either `ex1`, `ex2`, or `ex3`.)

`[(ex1)(ex2)(ex3)]` defines a character class that will match any of the following characters (just one character): `(ex1)23`. There are no capture groups, the text within the `[]` is treated literally.

The [`Pattern` class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) goes into detail about how patterns work.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Thanks, slip of the fingers. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In the first regex: `(ex1)|(ex2)|(ex3)`, you are going to match three groups denoted by the parenthesis (i.e. `ex1`, `ex2`, `ex3`), so you will get results that will match whatever `ex1` regex matches, whatever `ex2` regex matches and whatever `ex3` regex matches.

Whereas in the second: `[(ex1)(ex2)(ex3)]` there will be no groups (as you are using `[]` brackets and parenthesis will be treated as characters. So you will get everything that matches `(ex1)(ex2)(ex3)` expression.

Comment: Shouldn't your assumption be the other way around? If they are regex, a lot of crazy thing can happen.

Comment: (ex1,ex2,ex3 are any regular expressions)

Comment: @AttilaNeparáczki Yes, didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1):

- In the first case, you have 3 groups (1 to 3) each one with a sequence of characters, separated by OR
- In the second case, you have a character class containing characters `e`, `x`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `(`, `)` and no group
- The first case will match either `ex1` or `ex2` or `ex3` and assign either to its relevant group. So, given input `"ex1"`, it matches and will return group 1 equal to `"ex1"`, group 2 and 3 `null`
- Given the same input `"ex1"` in your second case, it will match all characters, one at the time, at each successive match, and each and every character `e`, `x` and `1` will be assigned to group 0, i.e. the whole match

Answer (score 0):

first of all, in regex, `[(abc)]` means match **character**: `a or b or c or ( or )`

There is no "groupping" happening in character class. (between `[...]`)

The other example from you is group match, different thing.

Answer (score 0):

`"(ex1)|(ex2)|(ex3)"`

If `ex1` presents, then it must be captured by group 1 and if `ex2` present, it would be captured by group 2 and if `ex3` presents, it would be captured by group 3.

`"[(ex1)(ex2)(ex3)]"`

This matches a **single character** from the given character class. It may be `(` or `e` or `x` or `1` or `2` or `3` or `)`